# SQL CASE com mais de uma condição

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gostaria de saber se é possível utilizar o `CASE` com mais de 1 condição.

Nesta consulta eu tenho cálculos que precisam ser feitos quando `a.operacao == 'C'` mas que dependem do valor de `a.DESCRICAO_PREMIO` (`'1P'` ou `'1/5P'`) para definir qual conta exatamente.

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  CASE (a.operacao)
    WHEN 'C' THEN  (b.multiplicador *  a.valor_jogo)
  END AS [Valor]
FROM tb_jogo_detalhe a
  INNER JOIN tb_modalidade b ON b.abreviatura = a.operacao
WHERE a.ID = 2222
```

Como usar mais de uma condição em um `CASE`?

Answer (score 2):

Tem sim. Olha só:

```html
select  a.*,                                                           
           case
               when a.operacao = 'C' and a.DESCRICAO_PREMIO = '1P' then  (b.multiplicador *  a.VALOR_JOGO)
               when a.operacao = 'C' and a.DESCRICAO_PREMIO = '1/5P'then  (/** coloca o outro calculo aqui e vai indo**/)
           end as valor                                            
           from dbo.TB_JOGO_DETALHE a                                                                               
           inner join tb_modalidade b on b.abreviatura = a.operacao  
           where a.ID = 2222
```

Comment: Agradeço muito a sua ajuda! valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Conseguir fazer desta forma!

```html
           select  a.*,                                                           
           case 
            when (a.operacao = 'C' and a.DESCRICAO_PREMIO = '1P')  then  (b.multiplicador *  a.VALOR_JOGO) 
            when (a.operacao = 'C' and a.DESCRICAO_PREMIO = '1/5P ')  then  ( (b.multiplicador / 5) *  a.VALOR_JOGO)                           
           END AS VALOR_PREMIO 
           from TB_JOGO_DETALHE a                                                                               
           inner join tb_modalidade b on b.abreviatura = a.operacao  
           where a.IDJOGO = 70
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem sim segue a sintaxe básica para usar o Case

```
select case when ((condição1) and (condicao2) and (condicao3))
            then 'Verdadeiro'
            else 'Falso'
       end
  from Tabela
```